# How can I slve this " Expected cv::UMat for argument 'src' " error?

Tags: python, opencv

I have this code, but I take "Expected cv::UMat for argument 'src' " error.
I applied this code to satellite image that clustered with k-means algoritm

```
kernel_2=cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(3,3))
dd=cv2.dilate(src, kernel)
```

Comment: Make sure you are passing a binary image to the dilate function.

Comment: I dont know, actually I'm trying to remove tiny pixels groups that formed after masked the satellite image but I can not do in no way